# Handling Response Output of REST Client in grails

Tags: grails, rest-client

I am sending a buffer from my api and api is requested from the REST client
in grails.and the Response is sending to the browser(AngularJs).
I am getting different response from the hitting the api directly from the js file and hitting from the REST Client  of grails.
 How could i pass the same content from the REST Client to the browser that i got from the REST API?

Comment: Could you provide a sample code or any details? Did you compared sended headers and data?

Comment: if(response1.headers.getContentType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")){
                   
                    println response1.headers.getContentType();
                    response.outputStream<<response1.body;
                    response.flushBuffer();
                }

Comment: Add all details  to your question. Remember to preformat example code

Comment: I am trying to return the response same to the browser from the rest client as i got it from the api. `if(response1.headers.getContentType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")){

                    println response1.headers.getContentType();
                    response.outputStream<<response1.body;
                    response.flushBuffer();
                }`

Comment: I have fixed the issues, with no changes in API. All the changes has been done in AngularJS.